# JasperReports automation

Tags: automation, jasper-reports, ui-automation

I need to understand how people in industry are testing JasperReports in automated way. It is exhausting and error prone to do regression each iteration and I would like to automate the same.

Scenario: 
I have bunch of (JasperReports) reports generated on code branch (jrprint, pdf, docx - various formats supported). I want to compare this set with pre-existing set of reports from trunk to confirm following:

1. Validity of totals and data generated on report. (content)
2. Layout structure remains the same. (layout)

What tools/frameworks are available, if any? Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.

1. Use the JasperReports API to generate reports automatically.
2. Export the reports to files.
3. Use a tool such as diff (or [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)) to compare the generated output against pre-existing reports.
4. Use configurable headers and footers to isolate and remove information that changes each report run (e.g., date, username, etc.) -- this will allow binary comparisons of PDFs, provided the data set does not differ between runs (i.e., always use the same test data).

This will work for binary files (PDF, docx, Excel) -- the diff tool will indicate that the files differ. For structured XML documents, you can use [Schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) to verify that the same XPaths are present in both documents.

Since `.jrxml` files are XML files, you can also use Schematron to verify that the layout of the source files has not changed (or not changed significantly; i.e., all the requisite columns are in place).